# (Bigcommerce API) - Adding an image to an existing product

Tags: php, image, api, bigcommerce

Working with the Bigcommerce API in PHP. Trying to add an an image from a URL to an existing product. Have been trying for some time now but am unable to and their documentation doesn't really explain how to edit or import product images very well.

Here's what I have. No luck with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);

require 'includes/bigcommerce.php';

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => $url,
'username' => $username,
'api_key'   => $key
));
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$path = '/product/78/images';
$object = 'http://www.greencoffeelover.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Test-Product.jpg';

Bigcommerce::createResource($path, $object)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own.

```
require 'bigcommerce.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
use Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\ProductImage as ProductImage;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => $url,
'username' => $username,
'api_key'   => $key
));
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$new_product_image = new ProductImage();
$new_product_image->product_id      = $productID;
$new_product_image->image_file      = $png_url;
$new_product_image->is_thumbnail    = true;
$new_product_image->description     = "";
$product_image = $new_product_image->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use you first way, just change your $object like this:

```
$object = array('image_file'=>'http://www.greencoffeelover.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Test-Product.jpg');
```

or use `createProductImage()` function:

```
$object = array('image_file'=>'http://www.greencoffeelover.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Test-Product.jpg');
Bigcommerce::createProductImage($product_id, $object)
```